# Reducing dimension of a DataSet with Autoencoders in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction

I'm trying to reduce both instances and variables of a dataset. The shape of my dataset is, say, `(x , y)`, with `y` being columns and `x` being rows. I want to reduce it to `(k, m)`.

However, in Keras, I do not know how to tell my program that I want that encoded dimension. Normally, I use `input_shape = (y ,)`, for example:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(y, ))
encoder_layer_1 = Dense(m)(input_layer)
decoder_layer_1 = Dense(y)(encoder_layer_1)
autoencoder = Model(input_layer, decoder_layer_1)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mse')
encoder_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=encoder_layer_1)
encoded_train = pd.DataFrame(encoder_model.predict(X_train))
```

If I do that, however, then `encoded_train` will have shape `(x,m)`, not `(k,m)`.

How do I change that? I don't know how to reduce both dimensions in Keras.

Comment: No, this is not possible with the standard formulation of an autoencoder, so it is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing both x and y will require you to consider your dataset as a single datapoint which I dont think is a good Idea.

Still, reshaping your dataset to (x, y, 1)  and using con2d layer should solve your purpose.